# Should the "try" be before or after the resource allocation?

Tags: c#, .net, try-catch

In the Delphi world, it was considered by some, at least, preferable to put the try AFTER a resource allocation, such as:

```
OracleCommand oc = new OracleCommand(query, con);
try
begin
  oc.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
  String s = oc.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
  try            
    return s;            
    except (on OracleException ex)
    begin
      ShowMessage(ex.Message);
      result := string.Empty;
    end;
end
finally
begin
  con.Close();
  con.Dispose();
end;
```

Is it the same in C#, or should the "try" come prior to the resource allocation:

```
try
{
  OracleCommand oc = new OracleCommand(query, con);
  oc.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
  String s = oc.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
  try
  {
    return s;
  }
  catch (OracleException ex)
  {
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    return string.Empty;
  }
}
finally
{
  con.Close();
  con.Dispose();
}
```

?

Comment: In C#, we use `using` as the gods intended.

Comment: Your `try` in the C# example doesn't make sense - returning a string won't ever throw an `OracleException`.  Perhaps you mean to put more code into the `try`?

Comment: It wasn't meant to be working code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's an even better solution: the [using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) statement.  Instead of this code, you can write the idiomatic

```
using (Connection con = /* some initialization logic */)
{
    try
    {
        using (OracleCommand oc = new OracleCommand(query, con))
        {
            oc.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            return oc.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        } // oc is automatically disposed here
    }
    catch (OracleException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        return string.Empty;
    }
} // con is automatically disposed here
```

Comment: +1 - Anyway, why not "using" OracleCommand too? :) I always do

Answer (score 3):

In your C#, get rid of your inner try, it is unnescessary as I've never seen a `return` ever fail like that.  You can also use a `using` statement for your disposable types, it will call `Dispose` even if an exception occurs.

```
try
{
    using(OracleCommand oc = new OracleCommand(query, con))
    {
        oc.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        String s = oc.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

        return s;
    }
}
catch (OracleException ex)
{
    // either do something meaningful here, or fail hard
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    throw;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The correct approach would be to place resource acquisitions inside `using`-blocks:

```
try
{
    // omit the OracleConnection using if you receive it from elsewhere
    using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(...))
    using (OracleCommand oc = new OracleCommand(query, con))
    {
        oc.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        // nothing was going to be thrown with just 'return s'
        return oc.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
    }
}
catch (OracleException ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}

return string.Empty;
```

Answer (score 1):

Any statement that could potentially fail should be within the `try` block, and that definitely includes a database connection. The decision of where to put this has nothing to do with resource allocation and disposal.

As long as any object that implements IDisposable is disposed appropriately, then you have done your job. This an be via explicit syntax with a try/finally block:

```
OracleConnection con;
try {
    con = new OracleConnection();
    // Do stuff here.
} catch {
    // Handle errors here.
} finally {
    if (con != null)
        con.Dispose();
}
```

Or a `using` statement:

```
using (var con = new OracleConnection()) {
    // Do stuff here.
}
```

The `using` statement is translated to a try/finally block. If you want a `catch` block, however, you will need to either fall back to the first style or put an inner try/catch block within your using, which is probably more overhead but in most cases unnoticable.

Comment: The reason it was above the try in Delphi (or could be) was that if the allocation failed, it would be disposed of anyway, with the component's internal code, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Is this some people as in competent ones?

You did that in delphi for the same reason you'd do it in c#.

If creating an instance of oracle comnmand throws an exception, your finally is going to execute and throw another one because your instance is null, or worse still garbage.

Naff all to do with using as such, except for if you were doing that you would n't need to close and dispose. If you had DoSomethingElse(); in there, managed and unmanaged considerations enter the bin.

Answer (score 0):

No, would be enough *in this case* to have only one `try/catch`, like:

```
 try
   {
        OracleCommand oc = new OracleCommand(query, con);
        oc.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        return  oc.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

    }
    catch (OracleException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        return string.Empty;
    }
    }
    finally
    {
      con.Close();
      con.Dispose();
    }
```

Comment: Sort of skipped past the point there, by not adding the code to instance con, which would be outside the try finally block and then been a definitive answer.

Comment: Correct, I was just showing the *idea* and not concrete code.